# ReCaptcha - Joomla! "Could not open socket" always

Tags: joomla2.5, security, captcha, recaptcha

I configured Re-Captcha for my Joomla! project. But its showing "Could not open socket" always. I tried many as described in various forums .
Is there any bug/problem with Joomla! 2.5 and ReCaptcha ?

Is there any alternate captcha ( free ) available ?

I tried "Tincaptcha" successfully installed but captcha image and captcha refresh are not showing and working either.

Any idea
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you created the captcha public/private keys?

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_use_Recaptcha_in_Joomla_2.5%3F

Fabio
@fcerullo

Comment: yes .. I had created both keys .... Its working in local host and also I created keys for my domain ... its not working